# Selenium Java best practices for handling different languages and locations, and setting dynamic architecture?

Tags: java, selenium

I am currently working on a platform that has multi-language options and also the language is defined by IP. So I'm trying to build an architecture for testing both scenarios dynamically. The domain is always the same: Example: `www.page.com` (If you are logged in from Britain the web application is loaded in English, if you are visiting the page from France the page is loaded in French.)

I have an idea to make different abstract classes with error messages for example:

```
public class ErrorMessagesEN {
public static final String MANDATORY_FIELD = "This field is mandatory...";
public static final String SOME_OTHER_ERROR_MSG = "Some error message on english"
//etc.....
}

public class ErrorMessagesFR {
public static final String MANDATORY_FIELD = "Error message in French"
public static final String SOME_OTHER_ERROR_MSG = "Some error message on French"
etc.....
}
```

In the test method i provide parameter "EN" or "FR" for example:

```
homepage.signIn(String location)
```

So is there any option to make for example:

```
if (location=="EN") {
   load the ErrorMessageEN
   //etc......
  }
```

The keys for the Strings are the same but the classes are different, so how can I provide different imports of the classes by the location parameter for example? Or are there any better approaches for this situation? Any links or ideas?

Thanks!

PS. If you need more info to help me please ask! :)

Comment: _Normally_, the best practice is to use DOM classes or IDs and to select elements based on those rather than on text.

Comment: Thanks for the response @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- but I`m already doing it... Maybe I wasn`t clear... I want to provide assertions for error messages for example :) And the language of the error messages depends on the chosen location or the language....

Comment: I can help you but need few details. How do you start your program(main) method? And From where you want pass the inputs to the code by saying "English" or "French"? And also please confirm will `elements` same for all languages?

Comment: @NandanA yeah the elements are the same, I want to organize the imports like for example to have abstract classes for ErrorMessagesEN and ErrorMessagesFR with the same key but different values, so when a language is changed the code will know from which class to get the value of the character